Chromium based browswers producing really large PDF files
I have a simple node js function which converts html string to PDF using the node js puppeteer library. Im attempting to convert an index.html file which is 400++ KB in size. However, the resulting PDF I got was more than 150MB. Is there anything Im doing wrong?
const generatePDFromHTML = async (htmlString: string, outputPath?: string) => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true, defaultViewport: { width: 1366, height: 768 }, args: ['--font-render-hinting=none'] });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setContent(htmlString, { timeout: 0 });
    
    const pdfOptions: puppeteer.PDFOptions = {
      format: 'a3'
    }
  
    if (outputPath) {
      pdfOptions.path = outputPath
    }
    
    const pdfBuffer = await page.pdf(pdfOptions);
    await browser.close();
  
    return pdfBuffer
}

I tried opening index.html in safari and use the CMD+P command to save the html page as PDF and the resulting PDF is only 15MB in size. Im expecting Puppeteer to produce PDF of the same size

What's htmlString? A runnable [mcve] would make it easier to help so we can reproduce your problem and start from something concrete.

I'm struggling with a similar issue - where HTML-to-PDF files generated with IronPDF create PDF files 2-3x larger than the HTML-to-PDF files that iText8 generates 1.6mb vs 500kb, 20mb vs 6mb, etc). It appears IronPDF uses Pdfium (from Chrome/Google) and iText uses their own proprietary engine. Sadly there are no details/solutions to resolve the size difference that I've found yet.
In any case you may find the trial version of this tool helpful as it's Optimize > Audit menu shows you a bit more detail on what's behind your PDF file size: qoppa.com/pdfstudio
Good luck.
